# Handling error with exception clause in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote this piece of code in PL/PGSQL.

```
    WHILE nbStatus1 < nbStatus0 AND StatusExec = 1 LOOP
        BEGIN
        SELECT Id, query INTO idQuery, Selectquery FROM temp_table_test WHERE Status = 0 LIMIT 1;
        
    
        EXECUTE Selectquery;
        
        UPDATE temp_table_test
        SET Status = 1
        WHERE Id = idQuery;
        
        nbStatus1 := nbStatus1 + 1;
    
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN others THEN
                UPDATE LOGS_TEST_DETAILS
                SET ENDDATE = NOW(),
                    ERRORMESSAGE = SQLERRM,
                    ERRORCODE = SQLSTATE 
                WHERE TRAITEMENTID = lastTraitementId AND QUERYID = idQuery;
            
                StatusExec := 0;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
```

I use EXECUTE to CALL a list of procedure, one after the other in the while loop.
Each CALL is stored in the variable Selectquery.

It works fine but...
I'm trying to implement a kind of try catch in case i made a mistake in one of the procedure i call in the loop.

So i did a mistake (on purpose) inside one of the procedure i call. But the ROLLBACK, remove all the changes i did, even before the while loop. it kinda propagates to all my code

Is there a way to ROLLBACK only the changes that occured within the EXECUTE command and then exit the loop ?

There is something to deal with savepoint i guess, but i can't sort it out

Thanks for your help

Comment: Read up on [savepoint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html).
They allow you to `rollback` to a specific point in your code.

Comment: thanks ! it helped a lot :)